# VoIP Push Notifications in Ionic for iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

From iOS 8 we can now use [VoIP Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html).

I found [this request](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/728) on Phonegap Plugin Push repository. However, it seems it's in status quo state.

So, I'm wondering if any of you guys have dealt with this before and if you have any guidelines?

Guys over at react-native seem to have [done this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-voip-push-notification).

Comment: I still have not had a chance to work on VoIP push for iOS

Comment: @SimonMacDonald: first of all, thank you very much for your indeed awesome contribution to the [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push). Do you maybe have a roadmap of when you're planning to tackle this?

Comment: @SimonMacDonald: please see my answer below.

I would kindly like to get your input on whether this would make sense to be added as a pull request (with proper changes to accommodate to your example) to the Phonegap Plugin Push repo. 

I ask merely because one can now use VoIP pushes, without having to use Push notifications. True, most people probably would utilize both, but still, the question stands.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating the plugin myself. You can get it on npm [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-ios-voip-push).

You can install the plugin with:

`ionic plugin add cordova-ios-voip-push`

and then use the plugin like this in your Ionic/Cordova app:

```
var push = VoIPPushNotification.init();

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    log("[Ionic] registration callback called");
    log(data);

    //data.deviceToken;
    //do something with the device token (probably save it to your backend service)
});

push.on('notification', function(data) {
    log("[Ionic] notification callback called");
    log(data);

    // do something based on received data
});

push.on('error', function(e) {
    log(e);
});
```

There are some additional steps to take in Xcode, so please refer to the [official plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-ios-voip-push) site to read the full tutorial.

Comment: How to use it on Ionic 2 or 3 ? If I use this line var push = VoIPPushNotification.init(); it says VoIPPushNotification is undefined.

Comment: Did you get any errors by adding the plugin? I'm not familiar with Ionic 2/3/4 :o, so it could be that the plugin system is no longer the same.

Comment: There is no issue, while adding the plugin. But I'm not getting how to use it. If I use var push = VoIPPushNotification.init();. It will through an error, cannot find name VoIPPushNotification.  Not getting how to proceed further.

Comment: Could you please create an issue on Github about this so that I can take a look into it when (hopefully) I get a chance to? Thanks!

Comment: Ok will create it, it would be good, if you give support to ionic 2/3 because yours is the popular plugin over web, for cordova voip notification.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, and hope that one of these days I finally get the time to work on it :(